# Problem in google site map for magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have generated google site map in magento but the url links are from old server

It is showing links from my old server now i have moved my files to another server but generated map contains old files

Comment: r u want to regerate google sitemap?

Answer (score 2):

magento sitemap url depends on  store  and its  Base Link URL

so you need to check you base url from a`dmin>system>configuration>general>Web>Secure and UnSecure` tab Base Link URL.

you need check also scope wise configuration

[image]

Comment: I tried this and despite having the secure URL set as the unsecure base URL (so all links are secure) my newly generated sitemap still has the unsecure URLs in it